# What are the treads on the side of the highway called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

On the sides of most highways (in the U.S. at least), there are rough treads just outside the travel lanes to snap a driver to attention if the vehicle is drifting off the road. Is there a name for these things?

**EDIT** (post-answer for clarification, needed the answer to find the picture)
From the U.S. Department of Transportation's webpage:

[image: rumble strips]

Comment: I call them *wake-up bumps*.  As you drive over them, they make a heartbeat sort of sound, or as I hear it, 'wake up, wake up'.

Comment: I've always grown up calling them "Growlers" its always sounded like the car growls.

Comment: It should be noted that there are several different variations.  The pictured strip is created by grinding away the pavement, with depressions about a foot apart and maybe an inch or two deep.  There are others that consist of raised asphalt bumps, usually farther apart, and I've heard of schemes using paint or perhaps glue-on plastic grids which produce a "tone" when driven on.  I've mostly seen the above scheme in the US Midwest, and it is generally called a "rumble strip".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Those are called *[rumble strips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumble_strip)*.

Comment: Wow. How simple. Now I realize I have definitely seen/heard the phrase before.

Comment: Also (at least in some regions) "Wakeup strips" or "Wakeup bumps".

Comment: Yeah, when they first started to appear maybe 1980 they were called several things (which I forget), but they are by now pretty much universally "rumble strips" in at least the US Midwest.

Answer (score 2):

There's another variant here in Australia (and NZ, and I'm sure in other places too), which is a set of raised paint lines *on* the road which will give you a rumbling sound as you drive over them. The same technique is used in transition areas from high to low speed (like a highway exit) or where two lanes of high-speed traffic will be merging, that kinda thing where you want people to be awake.

A sample can be seen [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/trinaaj/2629772299/), clearly showing the raised paint goop.

They're called, logically enough, 'audible lines', and are best defined as:

> ...a line on a road that is made up of a series of closely spaced raised pieces of material designed to create a continuous noise or vibration if driven on by a motor vehicle

([Reg 323A, *New South Wales Road Rules 2008*](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/nsw/consol_reg/rr2008104/s323a.html))

Comment: And yes, I'm off to edit Wikipedia to insert that reference too in a moment :)

Answer (score 2):

In Pennsylvania they are called SNAPs by PennDot, which stands for **sonic nap alert patterns.**

Answer (score 1):

They are called SNAPs: **S**onic **N**oise **A**lert **P**attern.

Comment: What's your source for this answer? In some quick [googling](http://safety.fhwa.dot.gov/roadway_dept/pavement/rumble_strips/effectiveness/state_pa.cfm), I found this acronym expanded as *Sonic* ***Nap*** *Alert Pattern*, so it seems there is some confusion.

Comment: "Sonic noise" does seem a bit redundant.